# seo friendly url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to make a friendly url for my website. 
I want to convert

```
www.example.com/city.php?city_name=Dubai&no_of_days=three+day+short+itinerary
```

to

```
www.example.com/city/Dubai/three_day_short_itinerary
```

This is the code I wrote but it is not working for city.php file. I have tested my htaccess and it is working for index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /city\.php [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/$ city.php?city=$1&no_of_days=$2
```

Can anyone help me here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /city/
RewriteRule /([a-zA-Z]+)/([^/]+)_([^/]+)_([^/]+)_([^/]+)$ /city.php?city=$1&no_of_days=$2+$3+$4+$5 [L]
```